# Is “European Peninsula” a common name for Europe?

Tags: word-usage, political-correctness, toponyms

[In this article](http://www.stratfor.com/weekly/united-states-has-unfinished-business-ukraine-and-iraq#axzz35kkzGJd7), Europe was called the “European Peninsula”. Is that a common name for Europe?

Here is the whole sentence from the article:

> We have seen that Ukraine’s fate is not yet settled, and with that, neither is Russia’s relationship with the European Peninsula.

Comment: I've never heard it before, and I would have assumed from context that it's a translation of some Russian or Ukrainian name for Western Europe.

Comment: no, it's not, we never call Westren Europe the Peninsula.

Comment: Not common, but not unknown either, not to this monoglot English speaker.

Comment: It's not common. It's actually weird and awkward. This is the first time that I've heard of it.

Comment: Are you sure they don't mean the Crimea? That both European and a peninsula. I can see they may have missed up articles. In context it makes sense

Comment: in this context I think they meant Europe, not Crimea, because Crimea now is part of Russia and it's impossible to have relationship between Russia and part of Russia

Answer (score 4):

'Europe' as a continent, includes part of Russia, so I imagine the journalist was trying to avoid contradiction by using a phrase that, though uncommon, is clear. Nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: I wonder whether the journalist means "all of Europe save Russia" or "all of Europe save the former Soviet Union", but yes, I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A *peninsula* is any land that is surrounded on three sides by water, just as an island is land completely surrounded by water. Debate as to whether Europe could be considered a peninsula is comparable to debate over whether Australia (or indeed any continent) could  properly be considered an island. That is, by a pedantic reading of the definition, yes, Europe is a big peninsula jutting out of the west of Eurasia. But no, no one ordinarily refers to it as such or treats it as such.

One might refer to *[the American experiment](http://www.nccs.net/will-the-great-american-experiment-succeed.php)* or *the [the lucky country](http://australia.gov.au/about-australia/australian-story/lucky-country)* for poetic effect, but unlike these expressions, *European peninsula* is not a set phrase. Europe is traditionally considered a continent in its own right, indeed, *[the Continent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/the-continent)*. But the author would not have chosen this phrasing idly. The article is published by a US-based international affairs research firm, and I believe the phrasing is intended to draw attention to Europe's vulnerability with respect to an aggressive Russia— as if the whole landmass of Europe were no different from Crimea.

Answer (score 2):

According to [*National Geographic*](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/encyclopedia/europe-physical-geography/?ar_a=1), who really ought to know about these things, Europe can indeed be considered a ***peninsula** sensu stricto*:

> **Europe is the second-smallest continent.** Only Oceania has less landmass. Europe extends from the island nation of Iceland in the west to the Ural Mountains of Russia in the east. Europes northernmost point is the Svalbard archipelago of Norway, and it reaches as far south as the islands of Greece and Malta.
>
> **Europe is sometimes described as a peninsula of peninsulas**. A peninsula is a piece of land surrounded by water on three sides. **Europe is a peninsula of the Eurasian supercontinent** and is bordered by the Arctic Ocean to the north, the Atlantic Ocean to the west, and the Mediterranean, Black, and Caspian Seas to the south.
>
> Europe’s main peninsulas are the Iberian, Italian, and Balkan, located in southern Europe, and the Scandinavian and Jutland, located in northern Europe. The link between these peninsulas has made Europe a dominant economic, social, and cultural force throughout recorded history.

All bold emphasis above is my own.

Now before anybody gets all het up and bent out of shape, *National Geographic* in [its encyclopedia entry on *continent*](http://education.nationalgeographic.com/education/encyclopedia/continent/?ar_a=1) explains that there are nonphysical considerations to what is or isn’t historically considered a continent:

> Coastlines, however, do not indicate the actual boundaries of the continents. **Continents are defined by their continental shelves.** A continental shelf is a gently sloping area that extends outward from the beach far into the ocean. A continental shelf is part of the ocean, but also part of the continent. If continental shelves were included in the total land area, continents would make up more than one-third of the Earth’s surface.
>
> **“Continent” has more than just a physical definition. To human geographers, the term is about culture.** The continents of Europe and Asia, for example, are actually part of a single, enormous piece of land called Eurasia. But linguistically and ethnically, the areas of Asia and Europe are distinct. The various cultural groups of Europe have more in common with one another than they do with cultural groups in Asia. Because of this, most geographers divide Eurasia into Europe and Asia. An imaginary line, running from the northern Ural Mountains in Russia south to the Caspian and Black Seas, separates Europe, to the west, from Asia, to the east.

So we all pretend this imaginary line separates one continent from another.  It’s a “culturally-correct” myth in that disabusing someone of their cherished myth is tantamount to goring their sacred cow.  People will find it insulting to their culture to call them out on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not common, but I've certainly heard it used. It refers to Europe as a peninsular of the Eurasian landmass. I don't think I've ever seen the "Peninsular" capitalised though, as if it was the name of a place.

Primarily a term suited to wide ranging historical/prehistorical discussions. It's just to differentiate that particular physical land mass from any cultural/historical definition of Europe which may be irrelevant to prehistoric movements of peoples, animals, languages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "European Peninsula." (I changed this because my previous response implied that Europe was not a peninsula, but my intention was to say that there is no such *proper* noun as "European Peninsula."

Europe has five major *named* peninsulas:

**Italian Peninsula** - Obviously includes Italy and looks like a boot.

**Iberian Peninsula** - Includes Spain, Andorra, Portugal.

**Scandinavian Peninsula** - Includes Norway, Sweden and most of Finland.

**Balkan Peninsula** - Includes Albania, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Bulgaria, Kosovo, Macedonia, Montenegro, with portions of a few other countries within the border, such as Italy and parts of Greece.

**Jutland peninsula** - Includes Denmark and parts of Germany.

http://www.toporopa.eu/en/peninsulas_of_europe.html

These are the major peninsula, I'm sure there are a few smaller ones as well.

I suspect that the author intended to refer to the *Balkan Peninsula,* but calling it "European Peninsula" is not correct. He could have said "southern European peninsula" or "European peninsula" without the capitalization and been correct, though.

Comment: Look at a map of the world.  It's perfectly reasonable to think of there being a peninsula projecting to the west from the central mass of Eurasia and to call that a 'European Peninsula'.  It's not a common term, but I think matters are much less black-and-white than your answer asserts them to be.  Look at your own list, it's extremely scale-dependent.  Zoom in a bit further and you can find 100s more peninsulas in Europe: Wirral, Tendring, Isle of Dogs, etc.  PS peninsulas is a perfectly reasonable plural form.

Comment: *Peninsulae* was the Latin form, *peninsulas* is the English. Plural *peninsula* would be a declension mistake in Latin, and I can't see how it would work in English.

Comment: I said these are the *major* peninsulas.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It might be reasonable to call it "European peninsula," but by capitalizing "peninsula," he's saying that this is a proper noun, which it is not.

Comment: The Jutland peninsula (whose proper name is more technically, and should be, the Cimbrian Peninsula, since Jutland is a different entity, including also the North Jutlandic Island, but not the parts of the Cimbrian Peninsula that are in Germany) includes only a bit more than half of Denmark; the other half is divided among the 400-odd islands in the country.